# How to force style change in jQuery immediately, before showing confirm() dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/67kaphgu/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("DIV").css("background-color","red");
    confirm("Background not yet changed");
});
```

In short, I want to highlight some element and ask for confirmation, before proceeding. However that element changes its style *after* the `confirm()` call returns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is because the `confirm()` call blocks the UI thread from updating. A solution would be to put the `confirm()` call in a `setTimeout()` with a very short delay:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").css("background-color", "red");
  setTimeout(function() {
      confirm("Background not yet changed");
  }, 50);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/67kaphgu/1/)

Another alternative would be to use a library which replaces the `confirm()` box with a modal, so that the UI is free to update at any point.

Comment: Thanks, i will consider this.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9xa7pwvw/1/
Will need to change processing though.